# Node.js webserver using HTTP and reading an HTML file. That HTML file cannot open other local files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

web.js File:

```
    const fs = require("fs");

    const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    const port = 3000;

    fs.readFile("index.html", (err, html) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }

        const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
            res.write(html);
            res.end();
        });

        server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
            console.log("Server started on: " + hostname + ":" + port);
        })

    });
```

index.html File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="picture1">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
    </div> 

</body>


</html>
```

Even if I give the img src my full path the website will never load the image. Will only load the image if I give it a direct link to the image hosted on a website.

Is there anyway to fix this? I need to access local separate js files as well.

Comment: you are creating a server that always respond with the html file and nothing else. I suggest you use express or any other library that helps you serving other files too.

Comment: The browser will ask your web server for `/image.jpg`, but your web server just  responds to every single URL with the same index.html file.  Since the browser can't do anything useful with that when it's expecting an image, it doesn't show anything for that image.  You need a more real web server implementation that responds to different requests for different URLs with the appropriate and matching resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index.html is composed of multiple resources besides the html content itself.
These can be images, javascript files etc.
The browser will make separate calls to the server for each of these resources.
You can confirm this by putting a console.log and print something like req.url.

Based on your question, it looks like you are expecting a single call (that returns index.html), to read everything locally available, be it an image or js files, and return everything in one shot. That won't work as explained above. That logic exists on the browser, which would make separate calls and collate everything.

So, you need to equip your code to handle calls to different resources.
Currently, in your code, you always return the index.html, irrespective of what the browser is asking for.

Take a look at this sample that I just tried on my machine. It's very rudimentary, but hopefully it helps you understand what I am trying to convey.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    console.log("request url is:" + req.url);

    var filename = req.url.substring(1);

    console.log("old filename is:" + filename);

    if (!filename) {
        console.log('inside if');
        filename = 'index.html';
    }

    console.log("new filename is:" + filename);


  //Open a file on the server and return its content:
  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

Note that this may not be the best way to achieve what you are trying, but I am trying to understand how you are thinking or going about it and providing an explanation and answer based on that.